# How can I change the data type depending on the received data

Tags: android, json, rest

I'm getting data using the REST api. JSON row looks like `"temp_c":12,` and I get it like this

```
int temp =  (int) list.get("temp_c");
```

The problem is that row can have int or double type (like `temp_c":12.5,`)and I have Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

If I use

```
double temp =  (double) list.get("temp_c");
```

I have Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this .

**Change to `String` first,then use `Double.parseDouble` to parse**

```
String str = list.get("temp_c")+"";
double temp = Double.parseDouble(str);
```